# AngularJS push two lists in one

Tags: javascript, angularjs, merge, push

I'm using angularJS and I have a problem:
I have 2 $scope:

```
$scope.list1{
Object 1,
Object 2,
Object 3}

$scope.list2{
Object 4,
Object 5,
}
```

and I want this result:

```
$scope.res{
Object 1,
Object 2,
Object 3,
Object 4,
Object 5}
```

I don't know what function to use in agularJS, I did use

```
angular.merge($scope.res, $scope.list1, $scope.list2)
```

but I got empty result
I don't know if merge is the good function so I need your help

Comment: please add valid data.

Comment: What nina is saying is that there is nothing in javascript with that syntax. There are **arrays** `$scope.list = [obj1, obj2, obj3];` and there are **objects** `$scope.list1 = { key: obj1, key: obj2 };`. You are saying list, so arrays perhaps? But you are using curly brackets, so probably objects then? But there are no key/values so perhaps arrays anyway? As the question reads right now the answer you need is: Go and read some basic javascript tutorial that explains arrays and objects, and then please come back and try again! (Or you could edit your question and **add valid data.**)

Comment: look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43759566/how-to-merge-two-src-in-one-dst-in-angularjs/43762165#43762165
this is my problem, I didn't get any answer so I write a simple post here :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *Angular way* would be using [`angular.extend`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend):

> Extends the destination object `dst` by copying own enumerable
>   properties from the `src` object(s) to `dst`. You can specify multiple src
>   objects. If you want to preserve original objects, you can do so by
>   passing an empty object as the target:
>    `var object = angular.extend({}, object1, object2)`.

```
angular.extend($scope.list1, $scope.list2);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use array concat.

Ex:

```
$scope.res = $scope.list1.concat($scope.list2);
```

Comment: That's nice! ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.list1.forEach(function (selectedItem) {
        $scope.res.push(selectedItem);
    });
$scope.list2.forEach(function (selectedItem) {
        $scope.res.push(selectedItem);
    });
```

Try above code

Comment: Can you please let us know if the solutions given  here worked for you?

Comment: Can you please explain why he should try the above? How does this solve his problem and what more does this offer compared to the other answers?

Comment: I knew this answer, I never tried other options... You are too rude